# how to build a custom scaler with sklearn standard scaler

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, typeerror, logistic-regression

i wanted to only standardize my non dummy columns and i used this code to solve my problem :

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

class CustomScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin): 
    
    
    def __init__(self,columns,copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True):
        
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean, with_std)
        self.columns = columns
        self.mean_ = None
        self.var_ = None
        
    
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns], y)
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X[self.columns])
        self.var_ = np.var(X[self.columns])
        return self
    

    def transform(self, X, y=None, copy=None):
        
        init_col_order = X.columns
        
        X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X[self.columns]), columns=self.columns)
        
        X_not_scaled = X.loc[:,~X.columns.isin(self.columns)]
        
        return pd.concat([X_not_scaled, X_scaled], axis=1)[init_col_order]
```

i appended columns that i want to scale to a list and used this code :

```
CustomScaler(columns_to_scale)
```

but i got this error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/3n/28x01nm12fzfbgmjk7v4d0jr0000gn/T/ipykernel_91107/477431600.py in <module>
----> 1 CustomScaler(columns_to_scale)

/var/folders/3n/28x01nm12fzfbgmjk7v4d0jr0000gn/T/ipykernel_91107/3682030523.py in __init__(self, columns, copy, with_mean, with_std)
      7     def __init__(self,columns,copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True):
      8 
----> 9         self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean, with_std)
     10         self.columns = columns
     11         self.mean_ = None

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is just because `StandardScaler`'s parameters are strictly keyword arguments: you cannot pass them as positional (the bare asterisk in the signature indicates this).  So you can fix it by changing the first line in your `__init__` to

```py
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy=copy, with_mean=with_mean, with_std=with_std)
```

Comment: i tried it but then i got  : `AttributeError: 'CustomScaler' object has no attribute 'copy' `

Comment: @sowfi In running what code? Your estimator doesn't meet the sklearn API by having init params that don't match up with attributes set by init, but I don't think that should be a problem unless you need to clone your estimator?